# Is there any way to avoid detection of selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using selenium in python to for scraping website https://www.owler.com/
but it's detecting selenium and others such as mechanize too.
I had tried the User-Agent = Mozilla/5.1 and Firefox too but still they are able to detect the same. Is there any way to avoid the detection from the site?
OR any other method to scrape from the site ?

Comment: Not without knowing how they're detecting it.

Comment: I am not 100% sure they are able to detect Selenium, because this interaction happens on your browser. What they are able to detect is the amount of requests you are submitting to their servers. If you are abusing here, then of course it is quite easy to be banned.